# javascript google analytics event tracking error

Tags: javascript, google-analytics

Can someone look at my syntax? I think I have something wrong here:

```
    html += '<center><a class="customerReviews" href="'+data[x].url+'#customerReviews" onClick="ga('['_trackEvent', 'marv1', 'cardv1', 'customerReviews']');"><hr/>Click to Read card reviews</a></center>';
```

This is being inserted in a JS file.

Answer (score 1):

You have an extra set of single quotes around the parameters.

`onClick="ga(['_trackEvent', 'marv1', 'cardv1', 'customerReviews'])">`

Comment: To test this you should be able to see it almost at once in the real-time reports.  It can take up to 24 hours to show up in the standard reports.